# Update with last known location?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, geometry, postgis

I have a large table of data which has about 75,000 people's locations
per minute of the day for a 24 hour period. The columns are:

ppid (person ID)
point_time (timestamp)
the_geom (geometry point)

My problem is that some (alot) of the info from the location
(the_geom) column is missing. This column needs updating with the last
known location of the person.  I'm struggling conceptually as to how to do this. Some sort of self-join on the table I think. But how to get the right data for the
update?

I've made a SQL fiddle which demonstrates the problem:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77157/1

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this will perform over a larger data set, but here's a single query solution, using two nested sub-queries:

```
SELECT
  data.ppid,
  data.point_time,
  CASE
    WHEN data.the_geom IS NULL
    THEN (
      --Get all locations with an earlier time stamp for that ppid
      SELECT geom.the_geom
      FROM test_data geom
      WHERE data.ppid = geom.ppid
      AND geom.point_time < data.point_time
      AND geom.the_geom IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        -- Cull all but the most recent one
        SELECT *
        FROM test_data cull
        WHERE cull.ppid = geom.ppid
        AND geom.the_geom IS NOT NULL
        AND cull.point_time < data.point_time
        AND cull.point_time > geom.point_time
        AND cull.the_geom IS NOT NULL
        )
    )
  ELSE data.the_geom
  end
FROM test_data data
```

Comment: Blimey. Well done. That's brilliant. Thanks so much. I'll run it with my large dataset now and see how it goes.